# Is there a way to use sql statements when loading .Rdata files into R?

Tags: sql, r, csv, rdata

I prefer storing my data frames by saving them as .Rdata file because saving them as a csv file will take much more directory space. However, when using csv I can load the files using sql statements (R package sqldf).

Is there a package available that can do the same on loading .Rdata files?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to use a sql statement? Just use `load`

Comment: I guess to maybe load parts of a data frame in a .RData? `load_sql("foo.RData","mydata","select * where age > 100")` or something? (note: that does not exist as such)

Comment: spacedman, that's indeed what I meant!

Comment: David, my data frames are very large, and I only need small parts of it every now and then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data columns are fairly simple types (chars, numbers, dates) then consider saving as SQLite databases via the `RSQLite` package.

This not only lets you load parts via SQL calls later, it is also cross-platform and multi-lingual (ever tried reading .RData from Python code?), and probably compresses as well as .RData files.

The downside is you can't store arbitrary R objects (like lists, or complex classes) very easily.

Comment: I tried to figure out how to save my dataframes through rsqlite.  Until now without success. Can you give me a hint about which function I have to use?

Comment: The `help(SQLite)` page has examples. Its first one saves the USArrests data frame to a SQLite table, then it shows how to read it back using an SQL query. I won't duplicate all that here. Try that then maybe ask a new question!

Comment: It works fine. However, saving an example data frame as a sqlite table will use aproximately 500 mb disc space whilst saving the same data frame as an rdata file uses 40 mb. Does that make sense?